# Changing color of Bars in a bar chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007, vba

I have a code in excel to change colors of bar graph but its not working. Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong in the code.

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 64)
End With
```

This code doesnt affect color of the bar.

Also, For all bars (representing values 0 to 200) I want one color (green) but for two bars representing two data points (100 and 200), I want to add different color. Can anyone please tell me how to to that with VBA.
I would appreciate your time regarding the same.

Thanks Very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The With statement specifies the objects or properties to be acted on.  Your code should be like this:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 64)
End With
```

EDIT - For the 2nd part of your question:

```
Sub ColorBars()
Dim chtSeries As Excel.Series
Dim i As Long

For Each chtSeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    With chtSeries
        For i = 1 To .Points.Count
            If .Values(i) = 100 Or .Values(i) = 200 Then
                .Points(i).Interior.Color = .Interior.Color = RGB(75, 172, 198)
            Else
                .Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 64)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Next chtSeries
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Doug,Thanks For your response. The first part worked fantastic but second part is giving me an error.
"Runtime error '451':

 Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did 
 not return an object."